# 1403 days in the beta

Tags: discussion

An update from our [previous check up](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/1001-days-in-the-beta) on the health of the site.

[image]

The important stuff, like % answered and answer ratio are still about the same. Questions per day is up, but perhaps that is due to seasonality. Same with view count.

This all ties in with questions we've asked before about how to make this an engaging and interesting community to stick around in, without catering to all the homework questions we get. How can we retain serious academic users?

The opinions of newer active users are welcome. What is your impression of the site and its policies? Discuss your thoughts about improving the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the 2nd point, of engagement, I think that the site needs to deal with real life issues and not just theory. the world is full with economic issues that should get their proper place on the site, and of course be analyzed with theoretical tools

That's something that is missing to me. I wonder if we can get some reporters or economic media workers to have some sanity checks on their stories

Comment: It would be nice if there were better questions made about real life issues. Too often though the questions end up being too broad or invite really partisan answers. But there is something to be said for the more grounded/established users to help set a standard for these kind of questions.